# IOS prediction app throws error to predict the .mlmodel in IOS14

Tags: ios, coreml

I try to use my .mlmodel to predict on IOS14 using the same method as described in the apple document link below:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/integrating_a_core_ml_model_into_your_app

I get below error. I could not understand what is wrong. My two inputs and output are all set as expected and model seems converted correctly from TF2 to mlmodel. Any suggestions how to analyze and fix the issue?

**/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalImage/MetalImage-124.0.29/MPSNeuralNetwork/Filters/MPSCNNKernel.mm:752: failed assertion `[MPSCNNConvolution encode...] Error: destination may not be nil.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error from Metal, which is used to run the model on the GPU. You can try running it on the CPU instead, to see if that works without errors. (If running on the CPU also gives errors, something in your model is wrong.)

```
let config = MLModelConfiguration()
config.computeUnits = .cpuOnly

let model = YourModel(configuration: config)
...
```

Comment: Hi Matthijs, you are right. Above code fixed the problem since it was running on CPU. However it produced another error and certainly it is about the model: [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Espresso exception: "Invalid state": Null output blobs [Exception from Layer: 54: StatefulPartitionedCall/StyleEncoder/sequential_10/conv/conv/Conv2Dx]
2020-11-24 13:45:41.697698+0300 HairS[627:70815] [coreml] Error computing NN outputs -1

Comment: That sounds like something in your model is not right. The model conversion utilities (coremltools etc) are not perfect and will sometimes produce models that don't actually work. In this case the error seems to be around the layer `StatefulPartitionedCall/StyleEncoder/sequential_10/conv/conv/Conv2Dx` but it may also be elsewhere and Core ML just gave up when it was at that particular layer.

Comment: Hi Matthijs, I have found out problematic layer. It is the convolution layer as named in the error even though the number is incorrect. When I removed the layer issue disappears. I have attached its image in the original message. The last convolution layer in the model is the faulty one. However nothing seems incorrect. Its bias values were discreet as a separate layer and I combined them as shown above. It did not fix the issue. In that case should I remove the layer and manually create a convolution layer?